# How to send a Disassociation Frame

Tags: wifi

Is it possible, in modern days SOs, to programatically create and send an 802.11 "Disassociation frame"?

Specifically, I'd like to be able to do this from Windows, Linux and Android. The problem is, I have no idea where to start or what to do or whether this is even possible. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I known that you can use [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) to create some frames like [Deauthentication frames](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication). You can read the code [here](http://svn.aircrack-ng.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not doable via standard `API`s. `802.11` frames are being sent by the protocol implementation, which resides in the `driver` & device `FW`. Applications interact with lower `SW` tiers (such as `driver` or `FW`) on a higher abstraction level - e.g. request to connect, disconnect etc. These requests are translated by the `driver`/`FW` to a sequence of relevant frames (in addition to other logic that is required to perform the requested operation). E.g., a `disassociation` frame will be sent as part of the disconnect sequence, bit so are other frames. Unless you have access and abilities to manipulate the driver code directly, you can't force it to send `802.11` frames on demand. Some vendors might have drivers that expose proprietary `API`s to perform additional operations, such as those that you request. However, even if such `API` exists, it won't be exposed or even documented to external parties (such as yourself), due to security issues and business reasons.

*Note* : It's possible to use various hacking tools, such as the one suggested by @jml in comment (see the link for details) to indirectly solicit the driver/FW to send frames. This is done by creating a situation which 802.11 protocol identifies as requiring sending a relevant frame(s).